# Testing database transactions

Tags: database, testing, transactions

How can I write and run automated tests that check that my database transaction strategy is removing race conditions?  At the moment all I do is test it in development by putting a breakpoint in the code and sending two requests, I can then see in slow motion what happens. This is not something I can automate though, it's not even testing really, just part of development.

Answer (score 1):

Your test can spawn threads and run two or more threads making the same request isolated by the transaction.

Comment: but in this case, how can I force the first thread to take longer so that the second thread tries to update during the transaction?

Comment: In the first request send enough data to make sure the update takes longer. Second request should be having only a minimal set of data.

Comment: I like this idea of giving a payload that we know will take longer.  Unfortunately this is often not possible I don't think.

Answer (score 1):

Perform a load test with a realistic work-load. Unfortunately, this is not easy to do. Race conditions are hard to discover on any platform. I know of no systematic way to find such bugs.

Sometimes you can exclude the possibility of inconsistencies by construction. For example:

- A transaction running under `SERIALIZABLE` behaves as if it was the only transaction in the system. Therefore, there are never data races.
- A read-only transaction under `SNAPSHOT` behaves the same way. Total data consistency.
- A `UNIQUE INDEX` will never violate its integrity guarantees.

As you can see you can sometimes make your code **safe by construction** so that there is minimal need to test.

Comment: I mean I try to do this but I effectively have a hole in testing, if someone for some reason stripped out my transaction management or bypassed/broke it in some way then it wouldn't be discovered until prod broke.  This is what I want to test but it looks like I can't, I suppose the only solution is load testing.

Comment: Right. This answer describes what I do (and I *do* have to deal with concurrency in my systems.). You can add asserts to your code like `SELECT @@TRANCOUNT, ISOLATION_LEVEL` and assert at runtime that you are being called under the right settings. I used this technique to find prod bugs that were not reproducible. Turned out the 99% code path was fine but in 1% of the cases the transaction was wrongly configured.

Comment: I very much like "correct by construction" code patterns. For example, all read-only trans I make SNAPSHOT. All low-volume trans I make serializable. Insert-only trans are always safe with READ COMMITTED. Now I have probably made 90% of the code safe with very little effort and high confidence.